# Bash Script - Replace Last Comma In Folder Names with an &

Tags: linux, bash

I need help writing a Bash script. I want it to go through a folder and rename all sub-folders to replace the LAST comma with an ampersand.

```sh
for dir in /home/john/Documents/TEST/*; 
do 
    # ***This is the part I can't figure out***
done
```

Say the folder is `'1234 John, James, Jack'` - I want it to become `'1234 John, James & Jack'`

Comment: Note that this would be a stronger question if you showed your failed attempts, so we had a better handle on exactly where you were getting hung up and why. This gets close to being a "please write my code for me" question, which we frown on.

Comment: BTW, your description doesn't quite match with your sample data -- the description says you just want to do a 1:1 switch of the last comma to an ampersand, the sample data says you want to replace it with a _space followed by an ampersand_.

Comment: The duplicate target used to close this question appears to be incorrect. I'm voting to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a suitable job for a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe); techniques using them for this and similar purposes are also covered within [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Extracting_parts_of_strings).

```
for f in /home/john/Documents/TEST/*,*/; do  # final / means we match only directories
  f=${f%/}       # remove the last /
  front=${f%,*}  # front is everything before the last comma
  back=${f##*,}  # back is everything after the last comma
  mv -- "$f" "${front}&${back}"
done
```

See this demonstrated at the online REPL at https://ideone.com/XcY4rw

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in /home/john/Documents/TEST/*,*/; 
do 
    newdir=$(echo "${dir}" | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1\&/')
    mv "${dir}" "${newdir}"
done
```

You can just use use `sed` to replace the last comma in dir name by &.

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.0.3 it is working perfectly.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Jg3wNf for an online REPL showing the problem. See how it treats `/home/john/Documents/Test/John,` as a separate argument from `James,` or `Jack/`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am sorry to say: it works perfectly. we.tl/t-zROk4hieXr (get a test archive here)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q6QJWc41 just get it here that's about the same at the end

Comment: Your `abc,abc,abc` test filename doesn't have spaces. The OP's `1234 John, James, Jack` does.

Comment: Then I got your point, indeed ;). Thanks!